# input textbox validations based on unicode

Tags: jquery, validation

I have applied certain validations on input textbox using keycode. how can i do this using unicode. in the code shown below, i have restricted special characters in the textbox as seen using keycode but i want to restrict using unicode.

```
$('.alphaOnly').keydown(function (e) {
    var pressedkey = e.keyCode;
    if ($(this).getCursorPosition() == 1 || $(this).getCursorPosition() == 0) {
        if (pressedkey == 32) {
            e.preventDefault();

        }
    }
    if (!((pressedkey == 8) || (pressedkey == 9) || (pressedkey == 32) || (pressedkey == 46) || (pressedkey >= 35 && pressedkey <= 40) || (pressedkey == 17) || (pressedkey == 18) || (pressedkey == 19) || (pressedkey >= 65 && pressedkey <= 90))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.charCode` (which is now supposedly obsoleted by `e.char`)

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's quite standard.